# Starts static's life time really on program execution?

Tags: c, static, c99, undefined-behavior

Does a static variable really exist for the whole program execution?
 I know there is no sense in this code snippet, but I'm asking myself, as I understood the c99 standard,
 when I'm getting into the scope of the If statement, It means I never was dereferencing an Object out of its lifetime.
 because luckily I was dereferencing the address where the static Object will be/is. So won't this be an undefined behavior as far the if statment is true?
 Or does the life time of an static object just begin on its first appearence?

```
#define UTHOPICALMATCH (int *) 0xBCAA1400
int *foo (void);

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    int * iPtr =  UTHOPICALMATCH;
    *iPtr = 5;

    if (foo() == UTHOPICALMATCH)
    {
        printf ("It's still defined behavior!!!\r\n"); // is this true?
        /*...*/
        return 0;
    }
    return -1;
}

int *foo (void)
{
    static int si;
    return &si;
}
```

EDIT:
In c99 on 6.2.4->3 its said:

> An object whose identifier is declared with external or internal linkage, or with the
>   storage-class specifier static has static storage duration. Its lifetime is the entire
>   execution of the program and its stored value is initialized only once, prior to program
>   startup.

So I'm not asking for, its life time after calling foo(), I'm asking my self, does this mean it's valid even before foo() is called?

Comment: It's just an example code with as already said no practical sense.

Comment: The only dereferencing I see in your code is `*iPtr`. This is before the `if` statement.

Comment: @Jens Gustedt Yeah and if its adress is equal to siPtr, im asking my self, is it thatn still defined behaviour?

Comment: If I understand your question correctly, wouldn't your example be better if you changed the contents of `foo()` into `static int si; return &si`?

Comment: oh yeah I'm sry, i corrected it

Answer (score 1):

**I am really confused as to what you are asking.**

```
static int * siPtr;
return siPtr;
```

this means that since `siPtr` is `static`, it's initialized to `NULL`. And because you never modify it, it remains `NULL` throughout the lifetime of the program. (Yes, **it does exist even after `foo()` returned.**)

```
int * iPtr =  UTHOPICALMATCH;
*iPtr = 5;
```

I don't see what you are trying to do here. `UTHOPICALMATCH` seems a random hard-coded address, are you sure it's valid?

```
if (foo() == UTHOPICALMATCH)
    printf ("It's still defined behavior!!!\r\n"); // is this true?
```

It only is if `UTHOPICALMATCH` is a valid pointer, because then you are just comparing two pointers for equality. Otherwise the behavior is undefined, but **that fact has nothing to do with `siPtr` being static.**

Comment: My question is, about it is valid AFTER foo() was called, my question was, does it exist, BEFORE foo() is called.

Comment: because in the standard static is described as its life time from programm execution up to its end, so it had to be existend, even before i have the possibility to refference it.

Comment: No, it doesn't exist before the `first` call to `foo` and after the first call to `foo` it exists unitl the program ends but you can't access it in `main` or some other functions because of its `scope` which is limited only to `foo`.

Comment: @Zaibis It exists even if the function isn't called at all, but how would/could you even access it without calling the function?

Comment: @Zaibis You are sneaking in the backdoor. C only concerns itself with well behaved programs. A compiler only need to make it so  static objects behaves **as if** they exist for the life time of a well defined program. The **as if** is important, it means a well behaved program cannot tell the difference if the lifetime really is from the start of the program, or the compiler/system just makes it appear to be so. But you're cheating with a direct memory address, so there's really no guarantees as to what happens.

Comment: @H2CO3 by choosing any random address and give it as many trys as the random adress is equal to the adress of the static object. And thats what my code abbove is doing. The code has no practical sense, its just to show you what im asking about.

Comment: @nos sounds simple for me, is there any source where this is proofed?

Comment: @Zaibis It seems that you are rather asking if the variable is preserved **across program restarts.** And then the answer is that it isn't. But if your code admittedly makes no sense, how do you expect a meaningful answer? `just an example != nonsense`!

Comment: BEcause as I already said, this code just should show what I'm asking for about the rules. As without this code I'm pretty sure no one would even get an idea of what I'm asking about. So why you are just talkign about sense of my code when ever I'm asking a question about the behavior of that code....

Comment: And i expect the meanign full answer because the rule as it is written in c99 has no sense, so i made a code snippet, that points the rule. and I'm askign does the standard it realy mean that way?! so whats wrong with writing sense less code thats respecting senseless rules to make clear about this rule is realy meant that way? Because, as i would be planing to wirte an compiler, its important about i had to treat even such cases or not....

Comment: @Zabis The problem is that you are asking about how something is guaranteed to be working,  by using code that performs undefined behavior. The undefined behavior invalidates the question in this case. A C program does **not** have to behave as if static objects are initialized at program startup if you go about writing random values around in memory. This means you cannot prove what you want an answer to with your code.

Comment: @nos Well the point is: with the if statement thats testing for equivalenz, If its true, i wrote into the adress whcih is guranteed for the whole lifetime of the project to be valid. So as I assigned the 5, i couldnt knew that it was valid, but if the random adress matches the adress of si, then i wrote into an memory area that has to be valid from the execution of the programm on. Ofc. this is stupid, but as the rule says it, this had to be NOT undefined behavior as its true. Otherwise the rule had to say "it's lifetime begins on first apearance" or smthng.

Comment: @Zaibis No, the rule does not have to say that since no-one can write a well defined program that can prove otherwise.

Comment: @Zaibis, no you can't conclude that. You'd have to do the test first. If you write into the address and it is not the right one you have UB, and all subsequent execution is jeopardized. In particular the test `foo() == ...` may then return `true` for any reason you can imagine, you corrupted your stack or whatever.

Comment: But why its then written the way I quoted? As I understood, plz correct me if Im wrong, the standard says a compiler has to treat that way as its written. And for the source writer it doesnt matter, because there isnt any meaningfull way of getting a difference between whole life time and notfyable lifetime.Sure it could also return true if its false cause of UB.But as the compiler HAVE to treat this occurance literally, there may be of let it be billion runs, 1 run, that might be welldefined, couldn't it? thats all, what my Question is about yes? no? and if no, why not(prefered by reference).